# Refresh View in Xamarin BindingContext

Tags: xaml, xamarin, view

I have a simple application using PCL for Xamarin, Inside my view called lvl1.xaml.cs I have a method calling for a new question from the db

```
public lvl1()
{
        ques = App.Database.GetQuest();
        user = App.database.GetUser();
        BindingContext = ques;
        correctAns = ques.correctAns;
        InitializeComponent();
}
```

The problem is, I have a DisplayAlert to say if the answer was correct or not, but I want to load a new question as soon as the user click continue, so I have this function (also inside lvl1.xaml.cs), when I debbug, I see that it goes to the constructor, gets the new question, but the view still displays the old question, how can I refresh it/ bind it correctly

```
async void GameContinue(bool continues)
    {
        if (continues)
        {
            var lvl = new lvl1();
        }
        else
        {
            await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `var lvl = new lvl1()` it is creating the new page in the background of the app, but you never actually navigate to it.  That is why you don't see a new question.  You need to call `Navigation.PushAsnyc(lvl);` in order to actually display the new page you created.

You may also want to create a separate method to get a new question so you don't need to create a new page every time.

```
asnyc void getNewQuestion()
{
    //Get question from db and set the binding context
    ques = App.Database.GetQuest();
    user = App.database.GetUser();
    BindingContext = ques;
    correctAns = ques.correctAns;
}
```

Then in your constructor:

```
public lvl1()
{
    getNewQuestion();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

and after the `DisplayAlert`:

```
async void GameContinue(bool continues)
{
    if (continues)
    {
        getNewQuestion();
    }
    else
    {
        await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
    }
}
```